# How to use JSON to parse data into android application

Tags: android, json

I can not understand this code.

I am beginner of android and java.

how do work  **doInBackground(Void... params)**, **onPostExecute(String result)**.

how pass value on this method from MainAcitivity.

Please help me.Thanks

```
class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

          String result=null;

          try {
              HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpGet get=new HttpGet(urlString);
          HttpResponse response=client.execute(get);

          if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==HttpStatus.SC_OK){

              InputStream in=response.getEntity().getContent();
              BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
              String line=reader.readLine();
              Log.v(getClass().getSimpleName(), line);

             return line; 
          }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }   

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            try {

                JSONArray array=new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object=array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String team1=object.getString("t1");
                    String team2=object.getString("t2");
                    allNews.add(team1 + "Vs" + team2);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }



    }
```

Comment: what's the problem with the code? what did you try so fat? any exceptions?

Comment: i can't understand this code... bro..

Comment: I would move JSON processing into doInBackground since sometimes, when objects are big, it also takes time

Comment: Sounds like you should read the reference and training documentation on Async tasks (http://developer.android.com/index.html#q=AsyncTask) plus ListAdapters (http://developer.android.com/index.html#q=ListAdapter) and ListView(http://developer.android.com/index.html#q=ListView) and then make a more specific question here. If your question is more about JSON parsing, then consider using Gson library and annotations to simplfy your life.

Comment: @Andrew thanks.But Reading is so boring.I can not understand many thing.I always do follow Lecture, Video.thanks bro.

Comment: OK. But be warned. Not reading because it´s boring, and then asking basic questions here to other people who *have* invested that "boring" time will not get you much love or good answers on StackOverFlow. A minimum effort to answer your own question first (and not have others do your thinking) is assumed.

Comment: yah bro..thanks.But i can not understands when i read then i can not understand any thing.when i do project and ask any person.I understand easily.it is my serious problem.

Comment: Android and java are easy to understand, unlike iOS. iOS needs video lectures but android and java are easy. Read. And stop asking "boring" questions on SO. We are bored reading your question. Please understand its our serious problem.

Comment: @siddharth thanks for comment.see Mr.Udi Oshi answare.I Accept his answare.He is so talent(http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.co.il/p/android-asynctask-example.html) his simple answare i understand all thinks.If your have technical knowledge of course you could understand any person easily.I think You give me better answare for me.I wait for your answare in this question thanks bro....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code basically is an AsyncTask - works in background and not on the main UI Thread - do post/get request to the url defined in urlString variable.

If the request is successful the task returns to the UI Thread in the method onPostCreate with the result of the JSON data. It parses the JSON and notifies the current adapter (of listview probably) that there's new/changed data.

If it's not your code I would suggest you to write your own as sometimes it takes more time to understand code than write one of your own.

-- EDIT --

SEE THE EXAMPLE [HERE](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.co.il/p/android-asynctask-example.html) FOR MORE KNOWLEDGE ABOUT ASYNC-TASK PARAMETERS

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result)  how get value in this method?

Comment: this is what doInBackground() returns

Comment: That is the parse. It is the try portion of the try/catch. That is where you pull specific data based on it's id tag, in your case t1 and t2. onPostExecute is adding that data to your allNews list in your main UI thread.

Comment: doInBackground() return,   String line=reader.readLine(); but this String value how go  onPostExecute(String result) ?

Comment: simple we always call for method with parameter. is it  onPostExecute(line)??

Comment: check the link in my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

When you get info from a url, here the http call, it returns data either in that you can read in the form of json or xml. You then need to parse the data. This json contains the string "t1" and "t2". You are getting those and adding it to your allNews list.